# Example on consuming JSON in Play Framework views

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.0, flexjson

I am trying to make the switch in a controller from sending JPA retrieved items as a List to the template engine to now send these as JSON.

I would prefer to use the flexJSON library for the task.

What I have is a Application controller with the method:

```
public static Result index() {

        ... Processing ...

    flash("success", "Items have been processed");
    return ok(index.render(Item.all()));
}
```

and a view index.scala.html like this one:

```
@(items: List[Item])

@import helper._

@main("Item list") {

    <h1>@items.size() items(s)</h1>

    <ul>
        @for(item <- items) {
            <li>
                @item.title                
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

These to perfectly show an unnumbered list of all the processed items.

Now, if I changed the controller to using flexJSON like so:

```
public static Result getItems() {
        List<Item> items = Item.all();

        String s = new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class", "description").serialize(items);

        flash("success", "Messages have been processed");
        return ok(index.render(s));
    }
```

How would i program my template in order to consume that json string of items?
i tried to follow this blog on the matter, http://www.jamesward.com/2011/12/11/tutorial-play-framework-jpa-json-jquery-heroku, but fall short on how to consume the json in my template views... any code example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just Sample it may help you.

application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
ebean.default="models.*"
```

routes

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET /cities             controllers.Application.all()
```

Controller => Application.java

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import models.City;
import play.libs.Json;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {  

  public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render());
  }



    public static Result all(){

        City pune=new City();
        pune.name="pune";
        pune.save();

        City mumbai=new City();
        mumbai.name="mumbai";
        mumbai.save();

        return ok(Json.toJson(City.all()));
      }


}
```

Template => index.scala.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        get_cities();       
    });

    var get_cities = function() {       
        $.ajax({
            url: '@routes.Application.all()',
            processData:false,
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend:function(jqXHR, settings){                   
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");                 
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                 
                process_cities(data);   
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus){                   
            }   
        });
    };

    var process_cities = function(cities){      
        var contentDiv=$("div#content");
        contentDiv.append("<ul>");            
        $.each(cities,function(i,city){
            contentDiv.append("<li>" + city.name + "</li>");
        });
        contentDiv.append("</ul>");                 
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get everything in your sample up until the code in the template. My javascript, ajax and jquery skills are quite low. If there really isn't anyway around ajax/jquery then i might take a couple of days looking into those. For now when i execute your example template, all i get is one text line showing my raw JSON data and no html tags <ul> ...

Comment: To view html just access http://<host>:<port>/   and to see REST service output as json you can access http://<host>:<port>/cities